# How to avoid markdown typesetting of $ signs in Jupyter output?

Tags: jupyter

I am reading an Excel file in Jupyter, which contains income data, e.g. $2,500 to $4,999. Rendered output is returning:

[image: the numbers]

How can I avoid this formatting?

Comment: Dollar signs don't do that in markdown.

Comment: Seems that it's LaTeX support in jupyter. So if you disable it somehow, you should be good.

Answer (score 4):

In `pandas>=0.23.0`, you can prevent MathJax from rendering perceived LaTeX found in DataFrames. This is achieved using:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.options.display.html.use_mathjax = False
```

Answer (score 1):

In Jupyter you can use a backslash ( `\` ) before the dollar sign to avoid  starting a LaTeX math block.

So write `\$2,500` in your markdown instead of `$2,500`.

A markdown cell like this:

```
Characterisic | Total with Income| \$1 to \$2,499 | \$2,500 to \$4,999
--------------|------------------|----------------|--------------
data          | data             |data            | data
data          | data             |data            | data
```

will be rendered by Jupyter like so:
[image: tabel renerd in jupyter notebook]

---

If the table is handled with typical Jupyter tools (python,numpy,pandas) you can alter the column names with a short code snippet.

The snippet below will replace all `$` strings in the column names with `\$` so that Jupyter will render them without LaTeX math.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx")
for col in range(0, len(data.columns.values)):
    data.columns.values[col] = data.columns.values[col].replace("$", "\$")
data
```

Before and after screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I am reading almost 50 columns from an Excel file, would like to avoid putting a backslash in all those cells

Comment: you say "reading" from an excel file, what is this reading process exactly? eg. are you copy-pasting the contents form excel, exporting to csv or maybe doing something in python code cell?

Comment: Depending on the process one could maybe just use the search-and-replace functionality of a text editor of even inside jupyter (hitting the `f` key in jupyter opens search and replace)

Comment: One backslash is not enough, you need two backslashes to escape the $ sign: `\\$`. See the [Working With Markdown Cells](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Working%20With%20Markdown%20Cells.html) example notebook from Jupyter Notebook doc.